# Finding a specific node in a node's children list in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
    Button A = new Button();
    Button B = new Button();
    Button C = new Button();

    somePane.getChildren().add(A,B,C);
```

---

Now, let's go to the far future. I have a reference to `somePane`, and I am interested in accessing button `B`.

Technically, one could do something like

```
    somePane.getChildren().get(1); // returns the second button
```

However, I am not comfortable with this since it seems to be prone to errors.

It occurred to me that it would be pretty useful to have some sort of tag system. Like this:

```
    Button A = new Button();
    Button B = new Button();
    Button C = new Button();

    A.tag = "A";
    B.tag = "B";
    C.tag = "C";

    somePane.getChildren().add(A,B,C);
```

Then you could do

```
    somePane.getChildren().getByTag("B");  // returns the second button
```

Is there something like this for JavaFX?

---

You might be wondering:

- Why don't I just make the button `B` a fixed property of my class?

  - Those buttons and panes are created dynamically. I can have several panes, all with their own "B" button.
- Why don't I subclass the `Button` or `Node` class and add this functionality?

  - Makes sense and I could do it. I would rather have a simpler solution though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways come to mind immediately:

Use the `userData` property:

```
Button a = new Button();
a.setUserData("A");
Button b = new Button();
b.setUserData("B");
Button c = new Button();
c.setUserData("C");
somePane.getChildren().addAll(a, b, c);

// ...

private Node getByUserData(Parent parent, Object data) {
    for (Node n : parent.getChildren()) {
        if (data.equals(n.getUserData())) {
            return n ;
        }
    return null ;
}
```

Or, use a CSS id and the `lookup()` method. Note that this will only work once CSS has been applied to the node, which effectively means that they must be part of a live scene graph.

```
Button a = new Button();
a.setId("A");
Button b = new Button();
b.setId("B");
Button c = new Button();
c.setId("C");
somePane.getChildren().addAll(a, b, c);

// ...

Button button = (Button) somePane.lookup("#B");
```